# Having HASH reference issue with perl

Tags: list, perl, hash

Having the following errors:

> Name "main::s" used only once: possible typo at line 22.
>
> Not a HASH reference at line 5.

```
sub addtwo {

    my $params = shift;

    my $s = $params->{structure};

    if ( ref( $s ) eq "LIST" ) {

        $c = 0;

        foreach $e ( @{$s} ) {
            $s->[$c] = addtwo( { structures => $e } );
            $c++;
        }
    }
    elsif ( ref( $s ) eq "HASH" ) {

        if ( scalar keys %{$s} == 0 ) {
            return undef;
        }
        else {
            foreach my $e ( values %{$s} ) {
                $s{$e} = addtwo( { structure => $s->{$e} } );
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $s = 1;
    }

    return $c;
}

print addtwo(
    [
        { a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 },
        { d => 4, e => 5 },
        [ 6, 7, 8 ],
        9,
        10,
        11,
        [ 12, 13, 14 ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: The 3rd error (that you haven't gotten to yet): line 11 you're passing a structure with a `structures` key, not `structure`.

Comment: Bug: `ref($s) eq "LIST"` should be `ref($s) eq "ARRAY"`

Comment: Tip: `$s->[$c] = addtwo({ structures => $e });` should be `push @$s, addtwo({ structures => $e });`

Comment: @user3047080: I think you've written far too much at once. Writing a program generally proceeds in tiny steps: you should enter a few lines and run your program to make sure that it compiles and runs. Then you have something to build on. The pyramids weren't built by putting millions of stone blocks in place and then running away, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Please*** add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of *every* Perl program you write. It's not a beginner's safety net: it's essential for any professional programming

As well as `%s`, you haven't declared `$c` or `$e`, and there's very little point in using `my` at all unless you have at least `use strict` in effect

To offer a "solution" would be to rewrite most of what you have put down, so I think it's best that you implement the advice that you've been given so far

But please do try, as I wrote in my comment, to write tiny bits of your program at a time, and to make sure that you have a solid basis when you want to add some more functionality

Comment: Would you please elaborate some more?